# Impact of changing Master Detail to Lookup in salesforce?

Tags: apex

I had three objects. Case, Payment-1 and Payment-2, Payment-1 and Payment-2 had Master Detailed relationship with Case. Now this relationship has changed to lookup relationship.

What could be the impacted area where I need to take care of ?

Now due to relationship changes
Case OWD is Private, Payment-1 and Payment-2 is Private.

All access to the Queue and Owner will be given based on the different condtions and Original requestor will get READ access only..

Comment: do you have reports?

Comment: Yes, We have reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following impacted areas need to take care of that, here are few points:

1. Rollup Summary Calculation on Parent object where automatic calculation will not happen.
2. Record sharing to lookup relationship objects.
3. Now, current lookup object will have owner
4. Cascade deletion if parent is deleted how child will get deleted.
5. Custom Report Types will get impacted. So test your custom reports.